# GCC/MINGW C: re-initialize globals as on entry of main()

Tags: c, gcc, mingw, mingw32

I'm making a test environment for C code that use global variables. I'm using the term to refer to any variable declared in C outside functions (with or without `static` qualifier), as well as local variables with `static` qualifier. Some globals are not explicitly initialized (thus initialized to 0), others are initialized to constant values.

I'd like a way to re-initialize these globals from my code, to the state they are on entry of `main()`, to simulate a re-run from the standpoint of the tested code.

So far what I do is actually terminate the code being tested, and re-runs it immediately using a driver program calling `system()`. This is clumsy and a bit slow (I guess because the instrumented executable must save/restore context to/from disk). I'm looking for a better way. If there is some runtime function that can be called and does the job, I want to know!

My environment is MinGW32, and I'd like to remain compatible with gcc under Linux32/Linux64.

The instrumented code is available to me as source (that I'd like to not modify or even examine), and is restricted to standard C99 library functions of `<string.h>` and `<stdlib.h>`, plus those available to hosted implementations (`<float.h>`, `<iso646.h>`, `<limits.h>`, `<stdarg.h>`, `<stdbool.h>`, `<stddef.h>`, and `<stdint.h>`).

My own code does not use globals. It would be nice, but not absolutely necessary, if my heap/mallocated variables survive the re-initialization (I could save everything I need in a local/stack/automatic variable). I want the instrumented code to loose track of all its heap variables (it can even be seen as a feature if heap variables that it failed to free cause heap exhaustion).

One thing that I vaguely thought of is adding dummy variable declarations at the beginning and end of the C source file with the tested code (it is easy to compile that from a wrapper), and pray that all the globals for that tested code are in a continuous block in memory; this way I can locate the block from the location of the dummy variables, and restore it at will. Could that work reliably?

TIA

Comment: Maybe you could compile with -g and leverage the debugger symbols to locate the globals?

Comment: You say "I'd like to remain compatible with gcc under LInux32/Linux64" Are you OK for a linux system solution?

Comment: @DavidGelhar: Nice idea, thanks. That could be automated. But would that work for local variables with static qualifier? As stated, these are part of my goal.

Comment: @PavanManjunath: Yes I'm OK for Linux if that makes the thing easier than under MinGW, but that's a second choice.

Comment: Try reading `/proc/PID/maps` in Linux and there, the third row is where your globals and static locals go. you can copy this region into heap before `main()` starts and restore it when you need it.

Comment: @PavanManjunath: Thanks; but would not that mess up with some variables of the heap manager located in that same memory region? The heap managers I know tend to have some globals for their use. I have the same fear for stdio.h that my test code use (but that one is survivable if I postpone any output to until I have the results in memory).

Answer (score 1):

You can always spawn some processes using `fork` at the beginning of your `main`, this way each process will have its own copy of the global variables.

Apart from that, I don't think there is a solution that ensures all the globals are reset from within a single process.

Comment: I see no fork() under MinGW. That aside, it is a nice idea, though I still need a way to tunnel data form/to the tested code.

Comment: right, sorry. It's `CreateProcess` for Windows, and it's not a portable solution. oh well...